# usb-host is not a valid device name - error when trying to pass USB to Qemu

Tags: linux, usb, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu

I have tried to use various variations of adding a `usb` device to my `Windows VM` but to no avail.

I have a `Yocto project` derived `Wind River Linux, with`Qemu-kvm` installed. The guest OS is Windows 10.

I do a `lsusb` and get -

```
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 8564:1000 Transcend JetFlash
```

When I try and pass a USB-Device, plugged in to the host system, to the VM, by doing a

```
 -usb -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,hostbus=1,hostaddr=29
```

I get an error saying -

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,hostbus=1,hostaddr=29 : 'usb-host' is not a valid device model name.
```

If I try and use -device `usb-storage`, it expects another input called 'driver' which I am not aware of.

I tried doing a`qemu-system-x86_64 -device help|&greo usb.*hci`, which gave the following output -

```
name "ich9-usb-echi1", bus PCI
name "ich9-usb-echi2", bus PCI
name "ich9-usb-echi1", bus PCI
name "ich9-usb-echi2", bus PCI
name "ich9-usb-echi3", bus PCI
name "ich9-usb-echi4", bus PCI
name "ich9-usb-echi5", bus PCI
name "ich9-usb-echi6", bus PCI
name "nec-usb-xhci", bus PCI
name "piix3-usb-uhci", bus PIC
name "piix4-usb-uhci", bus PIC
name "usb-ehci", bus PCI
```

Not sure what needs to be done to get this USB disk recognized in Windows VM, or which device type and parameters need to be passed. I tried with `usb-ehci` as well...

Comment: did you found the solution for this, i am also getting the same error

Answer (score 4):

If it is compiled from github source code and install qemu.

> usb-host default not support.

You necessary on qemu configure add the `--enable-libusb` argument and then install the `libusb` package. Then reinstall `qemu`.
`usb-host` will work!

Information can be acquired [at bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1320360).

//Fixed a typo above.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this exact problem, for me it was caused by running `sudo pacman -Syu`.

After this all my VMs with USB passthrough would fail on boot and the log files would tell me the following:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -device {"driver":"usb-host","hostbus":1,"hostaddr":7,"id":"hostdev2","bus":"usb.0","port":"1"}: 'usb-host' is not a valid device model name
```

I realized that after running updates qemu-hw-usb-host was missing, what I did to get it back and working was to reinstall libusb but also `sudo pacman -S qemu-hw-usb-host`

I truly hope this will save anyone with the same problem some time and troubles.

Comment: It truly did, thank you.